# Centos 5.6 apache permissions

Tags: permissions, apache-2.2

What's the correct setup if I want to add Apache2 VirtualHost /home/X/public_html (I'm getting this error: `[Wed Jun 29 00:38:45 2011] [error] [client x] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied`)

Selinux is disabled:

```
[root@server httpd]# sestatus
SELinux status:  disabled
[root@server httpd]#
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat confused. Do you want to give users the ability to publish web from their home directory? If so, see the userdir module:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html

If you want to just have a VirtualHost pointing to /home/X/public_html, you write a VirtualHost section.

Having said that, the error message "Permission denied: access to / denied" seems fishy. Unless I am much mistaken, / here is a directory and not a location, meaning your web server can't read the filesystem root dir, which would indicate something more basic is broken/misconfigured.

Comment: No, userdid is not the right solution here. I want to have seperate user (not root) which has public_html in his home directory and stores there a website. Also a VirtualHost param DocumentRoot pointing to /home/X/public_html.
The thing is, apache doesn't have rights to access /home/X/public_html (DocumentRoot) and i get 403 forbidden. I want the right solution (security-wise) for providing apache permissions here.

Answer (score 0):

Apache needs to be able to read the directory. The usual way is to make /home/X/ and /home/X/public_html readable by group and add the X user to the apache group.